# Delete duplicates based on string length criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

### Background

Remove duplicate city names from a temporary table, based on the length of the name.

### Problem

The following query returns 350,000 rows:

```
select
  tc.id,
  tc.name_lowercase,
  tc.population,
  tc.latitude_decimal,
  tc.longitude_decimal
from
  climate.temp_city tc
inner join (
  select
    tc2.latitude_decimal,
    tc2.longitude_decimal
  from
    climate.temp_city tc2
  group by
    tc2.latitude_decimal,
    tc2.longitude_decimal
  having
    count(*) > 3
) s on 
  tc.latitude_decimal = s.latitude_decimal and
  tc.longitude_decimal = s.longitude_decimal
```

Sample data:

```
940308;"sara"            ;;-53.4333333;-68.1833333
935665;"estancia la sara";;-53.4333333;-68.1833333
935697;"estancia sara"   ;;-53.4333333;-68.1833333
937204;"la sara"         ;;-53.4333333;-68.1833333
940350;"seccion gap"     ;;-52.1666667;-68.5666667
941448;"zanja pique"     ;;-52.1666667;-68.5666667
935941;"gap"             ;;-52.1666667;-68.5666667
935648;"estancia gap"    ;;-52.1666667;-68.5666667
939635;"ritchie"         ;;-51.9833333;-70.4
934948;"d.e. ritchie"    ;;-51.9833333;-70.4
934992;"diego richtie"   ;;-51.9833333;-70.4
934993;"diego ritchie"   ;;-51.9833333;-70.4
934990;"diego e. ritchie";;-51.9833333;-70.4
```

I would like to remove all duplicates, retaining the rows where:

- population is not null; and
- the name is the longest of the duplicates (`max(tc.name_lowercase)`); and
- if neither of these conditions are met, retain `max(tc.id)`.

From the given set of data, the remaining rows would be:

```
935665;"estancia la sara";;-53.4333333;-68.1833333
935648;"estancia gap"    ;;-52.1666667;-68.5666667
934990;"diego e. ritchie";;-51.9833333;-70.4
```

### Question

How would you select just the rows with duplicate lat/long values that meet the problem criteria?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name_lowercase, t.latitude_decimal, t.longitude_decimal
FROM (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(name_lowercase)) AS len, latitude_decimal, longitude_decimal FROM temp_city GROUP BY latitude_decimal, lng) AS max_length,
     temp_city t
WHERE max_length.latitude_decimal  = t.latitude_decimal
  AND max_length.longitude_decimal = t.longitude_decimal
  AND max_length.len = LENGTH(t.name_lowercase);
```

Where `temp_city` is the table that contains your sample results.

The above will run into problems if your `temp_city` also contains this row:

```
1 | xxxancia la sara | -53.4333333 | -68.1833333
```

You didn't offer a way to choose which row from amongst those whose `name` has the maximum length so both of these will be returned:

```
      1 | xxxancia la sara | -53.4333333 | -68.1833333
 935665 | estancia la sara | -53.4333333 | -68.1833333
```

**UPDATE**: If `max(tc.id)` is the extra criteria from trimming down the above duplicates, then you can wrap another layer on:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name_lowercase, t.latitude_decimal, t.longitude_decimal
FROM  
  (
    SELECT MAX(t.id) AS id
    FROM
      (
        SELECT MAX(LENGTH(name_lowercase)) AS len, latitude_decimal, longitude_decimal
        FROM temp_city
        GROUP BY latitude_decimal, longitude_decimal
      ) AS max_length,
      temp_city t
    WHERE max_length.latitude_decimal  = t.latitude_decimal
      AND max_length.longitude_decimal = t.longitude_decimal
      AND max_length.len               = LENGTH(t.name_lowercase)
    GROUP BY t.latitude_decimal, t.longitude_decimal, LENGTH(t.name_lowercase)
  ) AS tt, 
  temp_city t
WHERE t.id = tt.id
```

Comment: Thank you. `max(tc.id)` is the tie-breaking criteria.

Comment: @Dave: I added an update that should deal with that tie-breaker. The query is getting rather monstrous though don't show it to any children or easily spooked adults.

Comment: Thank you; the duplicate coordinates have been eradicated.